# How to create a mapping based on several vectors?

Tags: clojure

I have a vector define the columns in a table as below

(def column ["col1" "col2" "col3" "col4"])

And then several vectors define the type and constraint of the columns.

```
(def maxInclude [nil nil 1000 nil])
(def minInlcude [nil 200 300  nil])
(def columntype [int float int int])
```

Then I need to get a map as the following: one map entry defines each column, key is the column name, and value is the type and constraint for that column.

```
{:col1 {:columntype "int"},
:col2 {:columntype "float" :minInlcude 200},
:col3 {:columntype "float" :minInlcude 300 :maxInclude 1000},
:col4 {:columntype "int" }
}
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you define `columntype` as a vector of Symbols rather than functions, so:

```
(def columntype ['int 'float 'int 'int])
```

instead of:

```
(def columntype [int float int int])
```

Also note that `minInlcude` is misspelled and that I have renamed it to `minInclude`. You can create the outcome using the following (minInclude has been renamed and columntype is a vector of Symbols):

```
(def column ["col1" "col2" "col3" "col4"])
(def maxInclude [nil nil 1000 nil])
(def minInclude [nil 200 300  nil])
(def columntype ['int 'float 'int 'int])

(defn remove-nil-vals [m]
  (into {} (map (fn [e]
                  (vector (key e)
                          (into {} (remove (comp nil? val) (val e)))))
             m)))

(remove-nil-vals
 (reduce merge
         (map #(hash-map (keyword %1) {:columntype (str %2)
                                       :minInclude %3
                                       :maxInclude %4})
              column columntype minInclude maxInclude)))


{:col4 {:columntype "int"},
 :col3 {:columntype "int", :minInclude 300, :maxInclude 1000},
 :col2 {:columntype "float", :minInclude 200},
 :col1 {:columntype "int"}}
```

Clojure naming conventions for Symbols are hyphen separated rather than CamelCase. You should therefore consider using, for example, `max-include` instead of `maxInclude`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to go about this is to map over all your vectors concurrently. However, you're requiring specific names for your map keys (e.g. `columntype`, etc.), so the following solution isn't really generic:

```
(defn- constraints [cname type min max]
  {(keyword cname)
   (as-> {:columntype (str type)} cmap
         (if min
           (assoc cmap :minInclude min)
           cmap)
         (if max
           (assoc cmap :maxInclude max)
           cmap))})
```

This basically builds up the result for each "row" in the resulting map. The one caveat here is the mapping between the Clojure types int and float to strings. I guess you don't really want a constraint on Clojure types. If I'm right, you should probably change the data in `columntype` to use keywords (i.e. `:int, :float`) and change from `str` to `name` above.

Then you can use `mapv` to map over all vectors, fetching the first, then the second value and so on from each vector simulatenously and feeding it to the `constraints` function:

```
(mapv constraints column maxInclude minInclude columntype)
```

Here's a sample run:

```
user> (pprint (into {} (mapv constraints column columntype maxInclude minInclude)))
{:col1 {:columntype "clojure.core$int@607af697"},
 :col2 {:maxInclude 200, :columntype "clojure.core$float@4e8b32fb"},
 :col3
 {:maxInclude 300,
  :minInclude 1000,
  :columntype "clojure.core$int@607af697"},
 :col4 {:columntype "clojure.core$int@607af697"}}
nil
```